# App's badge number is stuck at 1 when incrementing manually from background remote push notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am implementing Push Notifications in iOS application.

In PNs payload which is sent from server `content-available = 1` is set so that app would receive both user and background notifications when push notification arrives from server:

```
aps =     {
    alert = "Hello!";
    "content-available" = 1;
    sound = default;
};
```

This is how I handle background notifications:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
        NSInteger currentBadgeNumber = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber;

        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = currentBadgeNumber + 1;

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

        return;
    }

    ...
}
```

By having this written I want my app's badge number to be incremented by 1 each time push notification arrives (given my app is in background).

This simple approach works perfectly for me on my 2 devices: iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1 and iPhone 6 with iOS 8.1.2, however it does not work for one of our testers. We did extensive testing sessions and verified that it does not work for him - our app's badge on his device is incremented to 1 the first time and then freezes - it always stays 1 since then. Here's how he describes the issue:

> The only time I consistently see the app's badge is incremented correctly is after a fresh reboot of the device and log in, which would make our app one of the few background running apps at the time.  Because I have many apps running on my device, many of which also use background processing (FB, NextDoor, WhatsApp), my theory is that our app gets background cycles less and less frequently the longer the device is active, which is why we miss opportunities to be called in the background and have badge number incremented.

Before taking this simple approach on incrementing badge number manually from background push notifications we also considered tracking of badge number on server side and sending its explicit number via `badge` parameter (as some of SO topics recommend doing so) but for the sake of simplicity we decided to try more simple approach and implemented dead-simple strategy that I am describing above.

So the questions are:

1) are there any insights into my implementation of this simple strategy that could produce unstable results for our tester?

2) If answer 1 goes negative should we 100% consider server-side implementation to track badge number so it would give us stable results?

P.S. Currently I'm adding additional logging strings to release new test build to our tester to understand if this problem can be related to `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` which is probably not getting called every time push notification arrives.

Comment: I approached this way and getting the stable results.  I am still on development phase, no idea how it will preform on App Store. But for the sake of Badge Count Maintenance, we are opting for Silent Push Notifications(content-available=1). One important note about silent remote notifications is that they are rate limited. So there might be chances that the pushes might get delayed, if they exceed the rate. No proper doc for what is the exact rate. I am also worried, can we go to App Store with this approach?

Comment: @dev4u, please see the answer I've just posted here. If you still prefer going with `content-available=1` I see no reasons why it can cause problems with AppStore. However given we didn't see stable results when we were using `content-available=1` approach I would recommend you to leverage server-side implementation. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I had asked this question we still didn't get stable results in control of app's badge when we were trying to do it on client-side using `content-available=1`.

That is why we have moved this responsibility to server-side: now we have number of unread notifications tracked on server so that server sends this number within `aps` payload via `badge` parameter. This brought us desired stability in correct increments of app's badge.

Now I would strongly recommend everyone to do server-side management of app's badge!! This server-side implementation that turns out to be rather simple would give you full control over this functionality.

Comment: Yes, Server Side implementation is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting first to 1 and then to 0. Sometimes it solved  this issues in my apps.

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

Comment: This issue is not related to `-[UIApplication setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:]` method. I did exhaustive testing and ensured that it is `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method that is not called with 100% guarantee when `content-available=1` push notification arrives. I am not putting -1 on your answer but it still is 95% irrelevant to this specific issue.